# React Query: isLoading does not update on Axios error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-query

I am using a React Query mutation to make a server side request, however, the `isLoading` property does not change when there is an `axios` error (500 server side error) and the `isError` property also stays `false`. For reference, I have the following setup.

**Base HTTP client class:**

```js
export class HttpClient {
  static async post(url, data, options) {
    const response = await Axios.post(url, data, options);

    return response.data;
  }
}
```

**Mutation:**

```js
export const useRegisterMutation = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation((vars) => {
    return HttpClient.post(API_ENDPOINTS.REGISTER, vars);
  }, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      toast.success('Your account was successfully created!');
    },
    // Always refetch after error or success:
    onSettled: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(API_ENDPOINTS.REGISTER);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      toast.error('There was a problem while creating your account. Please try again later!')
    }
  });
};
```

**Usage:**

```js
const { mutate: registerUser, isLoading, isError } = useRegisterMutation();
async function onSubmit({ email, password }) {
    registerUser(
      {
        email,
        password,
      },
      {
        onSuccess: (data) => {
          // set login creds
        },
        onError: (error) => {
          // set form errors
        },
      }
    )
  }
```

#### Problem

With this setup, `isLoading` stays `true` and `isError` remains `false` even if Axios throws an error due to a server side 500 error.

#### Tried

I:

- Updated the library version.
- Checked whether the code is executed in the right place.
- Lost all hope.

Comment: You're not actually setting isLoading or isError anywhere - or am I completely missing something?

Comment: @YestheCia they're provided by the `useRegisterMutation` hook.

Comment: code looks correct. please show a codesandbox or stackblitz reproduction

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem, but in a useQuery hook. Turned out it was because of the retries - if you set the retry flag to zero, you'll have the error flag set to true instantly. Otherwise, the error will show up by the end of the retry period, which by default I think it is 3 attempts * 5 minutes each.